# How to mix Form Authentication with other form authentication mode (like one time password) in ASP.NET ?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I tried to implement classical form authentication mode with an other option for authentication with username and one time password.

So I have Login.aspx and LoginOTP.aspx

In LoginOTP I use response.redirect to Default.aspx problem is asp.net redirect to Login.aspx since it considers user is not classically authenticated.

How to implement that business use case then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've got the same user base, but sometimes you want them to have a one-time login (e.g. for password resets) and other times to just login normally?

If so, for OTP, once you've validated the OTP you can use the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` method to log them in without validating against their normal password.  e.g.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("userA", false);
```

In the example above, the user is logged in with a username of "userA", and the `false` is whether to persist the login across sessions (e.g. whether or not something like "Remember Me" is ticked)

Documentation for the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` method can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a fictitious user but it's not elegant and probably insecure so your solution is better; thanks.